# Memory leak in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Will the following code cause memory leak?

```
var MyOptions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: "data1.php"
      })
options = new MyOptions();

var MyOtherOptions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: "data2.php"
      })
options = new MyOtherOptions(); 
// will the Backbone collection object with url
// "data1.php" be garbage collected somehow?
```

I am not familiar with memory mechanism of javascript. The question pops up from a C programmer hunch.

Comment: Watch "the breakpoint episode 8" on youtube. This explains how to identify memory leaks using Chrome's dev tools.

Comment: Of course it will be garbage collected - nothing refers to it since you've overwritten the `options` variable.

Comment: Nope but it will create a global variable. Don't forget to declare `options` with a var.

Comment: Agree with @CoryDanielson. That is why global variables should be used carefully.